# How do I go about adding business_day, opening_time, and closing_time to my app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What I want to accomplish in my form is like that of the Hours field in the  [yelp's business form](https://biz.yelp.com/signup_business/new) where a user can set an opening and closing time for a specific day.

Do I have to add a column through migration let's say `business_time`, `opening_time`, `closing_time` or there's a gem for this? Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: If you want to store information permanently, then yes you will have to run a migration of some sort. This is a very basic "how do I design my system" question, though.

Comment: So I just populate my select tag for these fields?